# javascript: object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a this object:

```
{
  "userAuth": {
    "id": 1,
    "uuid": "e30fa23a-bfe4-495e-b6ac-79d49cb9a5a5",
    "login": 12,
    "password": "",
    "role": "WORKER_ROLE",
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "uuid": "f0ca9c33-a5b7-48c1-9956-1d4d372475ec",
      "firstName": "Adrian",
      "lastName": "Pietrzak",
      "email": "test111@test.com",
      "phone": null,
      "avatar": null,
      "street": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string",
      "zip": "string",
      "createdAt": "2019-10-12",
      "lastLogin": "2019-11-29T20:03:17.000Z",
      "lastLogout": null
    }
  },
  "iat": 1570996289
}
```

and I would like to object destructing to this:

```
{
    "role": "WORKER_ROLE",
    "uuid": "f0ca9c33-a5b7-48c1-9956-1d4d372475ec"
}
```

how to make data object destructuring out of it? I try to this:

```
const { role, user.uuid } = userAuth;
```

Comment: `const { role, user: { uuid } } = userAuth; `

Comment: `const result = {role: userAuth.role, uuid: userAuth.user.uuid};` <--- isn't it much more readable in this very case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample answer. I think, that you should call userAuth property of your object.

```
const obj = {
      "userAuth": {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "e30fa23a-bfe4-495e-b6ac-79d49cb9a5a5",
        "login": 12,
        "password": "",
        "role": "WORKER_ROLE",
        "user": {
          "id": 2,
          "uuid": "f0ca9c33-a5b7-48c1-9956-1d4d372475ec",
          "firstName": "Adrian",
          "lastName": "Pietrzak",
          "email": "test111@test.com",
          "phone": null,
          "avatar": null,
          "street": "string",
          "city": "string",
          "state": "string",
          "zip": "string",
          "createdAt": "2019-10-12",
          "lastLogin": "2019-11-29T20:03:17.000Z",
          "lastLogout": null
        }
      },
      "iat": 1570996289
    }

const {role, user: {uuid} } = obj.userAuth;

console.log({role: role, uuid: uuid}) // this gives output, that you expect
```

Comment: Nie potrzebuję uuid z obiektu userAuth, tylko z user

Comment: już ktoś wyżej napisał to samo, ale dam Ci najlepszą odpowiedź bo widzę że dbasz o konto. Dzięki! ; )

Comment: Last line could be better changed to this: `console.log({role, uuid})` - no need to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Destructuring doesn't build an object. You first need to destructure into local variables:

```
const { role, user: { uuid } } = userAuth;
```

then build the result from them:

```
const result = { role, uuid };
```

Alternatively, use a single statement without any destructuring:

```
const result = { role: userAuth.role, uuid: userAuth.user.uuid };
```

Comment: I can this: const [uuid, role] = [userAuth.user.uuid, userAuth];
but I think that your result is better

Comment: @reactdto Sure, you can write it out to `const uuid = userAuth.user.uuid, role = userAuth.role;` (no need for arrays), but the OP asked for destructuring

Comment: "You first need to destructure into local variables" --- or one could assign to a new object during destructuring: `const result = {}; ({ role: result.role } = userAuth );`

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, but that's much uglier than all the alternatives :-)

Comment: @Bergi in this particular case any destructuring is ugly and pointless :-). My idea was that if you wanted to cover destructuring features (given that "but the OP asked for destructuring") then adding that another sample would make it more complete :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

You can have an IIFE that destructures the object and returns the destructured properties :

```js
const data = {
  "userAuth": {
    "id": 1,
    "uuid": "e30fa23a-bfe4-495e-b6ac-79d49cb9a5a5",
    "login": 12,
    "password": "",
    "role": "WORKER_ROLE",
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "uuid": "f0ca9c33-a5b7-48c1-9956-1d4d372475ec",
      "firstName": "Adrian",
      "lastName": "Pietrzak",
      "email": "test111@test.com",
      "phone": null,
      "avatar": null,
      "street": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string",
      "zip": "string",
      "createdAt": "2019-10-12",
      "lastLogin": "2019-11-29T20:03:17.000Z",
      "lastLogout": null
    }
  },
  "iat": 1570996289
}


const result = (({ role, user: { uuid } }) => ({role, uuid}))(data.userAuth);

console.log(result);
```